# How does inter-gear networking security work in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

The OpenShift Infinispan cartridge defines a number of ports which are used to communicate between gears[1](https://github.com/bdecoste/openshift-origin-cartridge-infinispan/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml).

Even after looking at the documentation, it's not clear to me what level of networking separation is provided by OpenShift, and whether there's some level of security provided e.g. that only other gears within the same application can access these 'public ips', or whether other organisations apps might be able to connect?

Answer (score 1):

SELinux provides gear Isolation (IE: so other gears can not interact with each other, thus keeping gear a from running code in gear b's space). The major part of the Network Security of OpenShift is handled by 2 routers (one for 80, 443, 8000 and 8443 and another for 3550+ port ranges). Because a node keeps track of what GEAR's can bind to what ports (and applies SELinux Contest to the binding, this keeps gear a from binding to a port gear b owns [in the 3550*+ range]). Routes from the 3550*+ range can then be made to your gear running on a 127.*.*.* address (thus locking down the isolation) and ensuring that there is no port crosstalk.

[Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/269693) has a good diagram of this.

Answer (score 0):

The network security is done via SELinux.  No gear can access another gears services directly (except for port 8080 which is publicly available), the exception being if you generate a scaled application with a database, the database sits on it's own gear and is accessible from more than just itself.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the Infinispan cartridge counts as a database in this case? What has access to the ports exposed by a database? Is it just gears from the associated application?

Comment: @davidillsley The gears in the application have access to the ports exposed by the database.  In a scaled application, the database port is also exposed to the internet.

Comment: Databases that get their own gears using a scaled application are limited to those added as cartridges (postgres, mysql, mongodb)